# Units and Measurements

Tags: 3d-view, units, measurement

Scene Properties Units are set to Imperial, which makes each square on the grid one foot. Theoretically, that is.  The problem: Viewport Overlay will not allow for 12 subdivisions. Instead the grid is stuck at 3 subdivisions. In another file, the subdivisions are stuck at 10.

Any ideas why this is and how I can correct it? I'm using Blender 2.90.1

Comment: I think you may not be able to zoom in to inch level without orthographic. The 10 thing is weird, unless you're actually much farther zoomed out than you thought you were.

Comment: Would this be a bug with 2.90.1? The subdivision number has no bearing on the grid. All is stuck where it is.

Comment: Subdivision number? R U talking about Unit scale?

Comment: This is sounding like a GPU thing. A friend has a refurbished laptop with Windows 10, but the GPU cannot handle blender 2.80 & up. Look for other things that seem like graphics glitches, and check how old your GPU is (Intel HD Graphics is a GPU in case you didn't know. I didn't)

Comment: Is this problem just in one file, or does it manifest in the default file with default settings?

Comment: Thanks, ZargulTheWizard. The 12  subdivisions are visible only in orthographic, and I need to be zoomed in really close. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Yeah, that's what kinda broke my loyalty to Imperial in Blender :( . The grid does not divide below inches unless your in metric, where division goes as far as you need to (but always only in orthrographic).